# Value of logrotate wild card

Tags: wildcard, logrotate

Let's say I have a logrotate config file as below:

```
"/data/logs/*.log" {
  daily
  rotate 5
  compress
  missingok
  notifempty
  prerotate
    echo "file name is: <file_name>"
  endscript
}
```

In the `prerotate` I'd like to perform a command in which I need to know of the wildcard's value. For the sake of this question let's say my command is very simple and is just the `echo` of the wildcard value.

How can I do this without creating a separate config definition for each possible value of the wildcard? Is there a way to point to the wildcard's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run `prerotate` for every file instead of just once for the whole group, you need to add the `nosharedscripts` option. The name of the file is then handed to the script as the first argument, so if you have a script like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "$1"
```

then you should be able to use this:

```
"/data/logs/*.log" {
  daily
  rotate 5
  compress
  missingok
  notifempty
  nosharedscripts
  prerotate
    /path/to/your/script
  endscript
}
```

Comment: Are you saying if I use `$1` in the prerotate or postrotate, then it has the value of the wildcard file?

Comment: @alamoot I understand that the filename is handed to the command, but I'm not sure if you can just use a plain `echo` and have the filename printed. If you use a script instead, you're more flexible, as if at all, the filename is just tacked on at the end of the command.

Comment: the `echo` command was just an example I used to ask my question on SO. I have used the `$1` as you've suggested and it works given that the `sharedscripts`  config is not present